# MySQL join with given hash table values

Tags: mysql

I have a query that returns a value per client Id.
Each client works with different currency so I need to convert this value to USD.

I have a Hash talbe in memory with those conversion rate:

For example  I have this rates to USD (I made the numbers..)

```
{
  "EUR": 1.1
  "SEK": 0.8
  "GBP": 9
}
```

How can I convert the value by the rate?

I have this query:

```
SELECT client_id, val
FROM table
```

I created a hash table mapping between clientId and its rate (In my Java code as this might change) and I want to JOIN it with those given values, so I would be able to wrap this with external SELECT clause:

```
SELECT values.client_id, values.val / rates.rate
FROM (
  SELECT client_id, val
  FROM table AS values
  LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   // Hash Table Data
   // client_id, rate
  AS rates on rates.client_id = values.client_id
)
```

Rates are not in DB.  I am trying to build the query using JAVA and execute it.

Is this possible?

Comment: Is this hash table within mysql? If yes, you can do it. If not, then you cannot. So simple. Btw, mysql does have a memory table engine type.

Comment: No its not,  I want to build the query somehow. @Shadow

Comment: Then you cannot do it within MySQL. You must bring the data into MySQL for a join to work. json_table function may help with that or you can use a series of unions to construct a derived table on the fly. But you will need java code to generate the sql statement for you.

Comment: OK so lets assume I have the currencies in JSON.  How can join data from there by id field?  
Json should look like this: {"client1":1, "client2":0.55} or like this?  [{"clientId": "client1", "rate": 1}, {"clientId": client2, "rate":0.55}]

Comment: You can probably work with both - you need to find the right expressions the extract the data into tabular client id - rate pairs. But would be a lot simpler to have a memory table within mysql that stores these data.